# How to detect encoding of a file format

Tags: python-3.x, encoding, chardet

I have files in bucket of s3 and i am reading them as stream. I want to detect the encoding of the diffrent files.

I used chardet library , i am getting this error:

```
TypeError: Expected object of type bytes or bytearray, got: <class 
'botocore.response.StreamingBody'>
```

and my code is:

```
a = (obj.get()['Body'])
reader = chardet.detect(a).get('encoding')
print(reader)
```

And is there any other ways to detect the encoding before opening of a file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got this

you need to use read function again!

```
      a = (obj.get()['Body']._raw_stream).read()
```